# How to combine functions AGGREGATE + VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using this formula on Excel2013, however it's not working.

[image]

My expected result is -626.

```
| café    | 600 | 392  | 208  |
| water   | 300 | 248  | 52   |
| milk    | 502 | 905  | -403 |
| orange  | 503 | 1130 | -627 |
| coconut | 504 | 405  | 99   |
| scream  | 505 | 630  | -125 |
```

Am I missing out on something? How to make it work?

Thanks you!

Comment: What answers do you expect?

Comment: It wont work in `Excel 2013` since it expects the same number of rows to be selected to return as an array even if you hit the `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. Try selecting consecutive 6 or 2 rows and then apply the formula to show the output as `-627`. Instead you could try `=AGGREGATE(15,6,B1:D6,1)` to return `-627` if thats what you are trying to achieve . Still now I think kind of unsure what you are looking at to expect

Comment: Hi @Florin, my expect result is -627.

Comment: Hi @MayukhBhattacharya, selecting multiple cells actually works. Is it possible to use another solution? I tried `AGGREGATE+INDEX+MATCH` also not working.

Comment: @YenDang yeah thats what i tried to say, actually. If you want to return the output as `-627` then why not simply use `=AGGREGATE(15,6,B1:D6,1)` in anyways you are not returning the `item` you need only the value right?

Comment: Hi @MayukhBhattacharya, In fact, my formula looks like this:
`AGGREGATE(15,6,VLOOKUP(..) * array1 + array2, 1)`  so I want it to work with arrays.

Comment: Ah, but then your query is incomplete. if you have some other arrays here, then you need to show? also instead of using the `VLOOKUP()`, you could try `=AGGREGATE(15,6,(B2:D6)*(aaray1+array2),1)`?

Comment: Why not use this formula: `=MIN(D1:D6)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D9`

```
=AGGREGATE(
    15,
    6,
    MMULT(
        N(
            $A$9:$A$11 =
                TRANSPOSE(
                    $A$1:$A$6
                )
        ),
        $D$1:$D$6
    ) + $B$9:$B$11,
    1
)
```

---

**Note:** Since its an array formula, based on your excel version need to hit  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

`=MIN(MINIFS(D1:D6,A1:A6,A9:A11)+B9:B11)` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! `MINIFS` don't exist on Excel2013. also it's not clear to me why `VLOOKUP` doesn't work in array formulas. this is really a problem.

Comment: I think your VLOOKUP version might work if you enter the formula with Ctrl+shift+enter. Can you confirm? `=AGGREGATE(15,6,VLOOKUP(A9:A11,A1:D6,4,0)+B9:B11,1)`

Comment: @P.b `=AGGREGATE(15,6,VLOOKUP(A9:A11,A1:D6,4,0)+B9:B11,1)` this will not work. As because it needs to select at least two or the number of cells the lookup value is selected for to get the desired output, since its an array return. For the OP's post -- If you hit `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` in a single cell it will give you `209` which OP has already shown, but if you select three cells and hit `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` it will return the desired output as `-626` but it doesnt make sense to have three cells for a single output with the same values.

Comment: In Office 365 taking in 3 cells in the VLOOKUP for lookup argument will return an array of 3 results. In Excel 2013 it'll only return the result for the intersection, meaning the first lookup argument in this case. (Thanks to Mayukh for testing)

Comment: @YenDang : Older versions of Excel use `Implicit Intersection`, not `M365`. So you have used `A9:A11`, on the first row this is `A9`, second row, `A10` etc. Copy the exact formula to `C9:C12`, then highlight the `VLOOKUP()` in the formula bar, you will understand.